# Python Pandas styling changing background color of whole row based on value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to change the background color to green, yellow and red based on the `lastupdate` column below:

Reproducible code:

```
testdf = pd.DataFrame({'title': {0: 'Test1',
  1: 'Test2',
  2: 'Test3',
  3: 'Test4',
  4: 'Test5',
  5: 'Test6',
  6: 'Test7',
  7: 'Test8'},
 'url': {0: 'link',
  1: 'link',
  2: 'link',
  3: 'link',
  4: 'link',
  5: 'link',
  6: 'link',
  7: 'link'},
 'status': {0: 'In_progress',
  1: 'In_progress',
  2: 'In_progress',
  3: 'In_progress',
  4: 'In_progress',
  5: 'In_progress',
  6: 'In_progress',
  7: 'In_progress'},
 'age': {0: 12, 1: 14, 2: 31, 3: 42, 4: 81, 5: 104, 6: 105, 7: 138},
 'lastupdate': {0: 6,
  1: 18,
  2: 20,
  3: 20,
  4: 20,
  5: 19,
  6: 90,
  7: 111}})
```

Data:

```
    title   url status  age lastupdate
0   Test1   link    In_progress 12  6
1   Test2   link    In_progress 14  18
2   Test3   link    In_progress 31  20
3   Test4   link    In_progress 42  20
4   Test5   link    In_progress 81  20
5   Test6   link    In_progress 104 19
6   Test7   link    In_progress 105 90
7   Test8   link    In_progress 138 111
```

The logic for green, yellow, red is as follows:

```
def highlight(s):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    if s <= 14: 
        return 'background-color: green'
    elif (s > 14 & s < 30):
        return 'background-color: yellow'
    elif s > 30:
        return 'background-color: red'
```

I am struggling to apply to the testdf. I can use `testdf.style.apply` but it tends to apply to the whole table. Is there a way to modify this function and apply on one column and change the background of all the rows ?

The output should look as follows:

[image]

Eventually I will use this to send email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you use `lastupdate` to determine the whole row, you want to `apply` on row and return the format css for each cell. Something like this:

```
def highlight(row):
    '''
    highlight the maximum in a Series yellow.
    '''
    s = row['lastupdate']
    if s <= 14: 
        css = 'background-color: green'
    elif (14 < s < 30):
        css = 'background-color: yellow'
    else:
        css = 'background-color: red'

    return [css] * len(row)

df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. This is exactly what I needed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: One last question. How do I convert this to html to send via email ? When I do `df.style.apply(highlight, axis=1).to_html()` I get error

Comment: Chain it with `.render`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I like to use this same code but I only need the color the whole row where the theshold is breaced, not the whole data frame. For example in this case row 7, needs to be red, row 2,3, and 4 needs to be yellow. how can I do this?

Comment: @user1471980 not sure I followed. The current answer does exactly that, coloring the whole row based on `lastupdate`.